# bindService, unbindService, android and non-sunny-day-scenarios

Tags: android, service

This is more a question about the Android internals to people who stumbled onto similar doubts in the past.

Question is pretty simple in essence:

assuming i have a bind service that delivers certain functionality to applications running in other processes - how can i know if the caller requesting functionality is still there?

assume i have a remote service that implements remote callbacks, like mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html), how can i be sure there is still a class to receive the callback? how is cleaning performed? is binding automatically closed when application leaves / crashes, the way it happens with open files or sockets?

and finally:

if a remote application crashes without unbinding from my service, will it keep running, even if that was the last application using the service?

thanks for all the tips, guys, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this, and even if an external component leaks a ServiceConnection by failing to unbind, Android will kill the service (provided that it hasn't been started with startService, and is not bound elsewhere). onUnbind and onDestroy will be called in this case.

As far as detecting whether the components that registered callbacks are still alive, I believe that CommonsWare is correct in that you should just try the callback. However, you should be able to wake up the calling component, and wake it back up.

There are two kinds of desired behavior on a callback if the external component is dead (so that the normal callback will fail):

1. An external component only needs to receive a callback from your service if the component in question is still alive. In this case, just swallow (and log) the exception thrown by trying to invoke a dead callback.
2. An external component, which is no longer alive, SHOULD be woken up when your service attempts to callback. Since you can't do this through normal callback methods, you'll need to fire off some intent to wake up the dead component. The easy way to do this is to provide methods for a component to register a PendingIntent with your service. If a normal callback fails, simply fire off the PendingIntent. The external component (Which should have registered as a receiver for the associated Intent), will wake up, and appropriately respond to the intent, possibly by reBinding and invoking additional methods to retrieve the result of the failed callback. A caveat of this is that if you permit callers to die, and they will expect to wake up, you'll need the service to start itself via startService(), and stop appropriately, since otherwise you may get collected while you're doing the requested work before firing the PendingIntent

Comment: Thanks bunches. So i guess the ultimate way would be to 'heartbeat' from time to time my listeners and simply clean up those who cause exception. that sounds quite fine, pretty much like networking.

it's also good to know that android itself will take care of removing dead bindings. that pretty much eliminates the problem of having a running process when there's noone interested in it.

Comment: No need for heartbeats IMO. See my changes in the answer for one way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

> assuming i have a bind service that delivers certain functionality to applications running in other processes - how can i know if the caller requesting functionality is still there?

You don't, AFAIK.

> assume i have a remote service that implements remote callbacks, like mentioned here, how can i be sure there is still a class to receive the callback?

You should get a `RemoteObjectException` if the callback object is no longer usable (e.g., the client is gone).

> how is cleaning performed?

I have no idea what this means in this context, sorry.

> is binding automatically closed when application leaves / crashes, the way it happens with open files or sockets?

Yes, though you are not notified of this fact in the service.

> if a remote application crashes without unbinding from my service, will it keep running, even if that was the last application using the service?

I do not know for certain. I would hope Android would detect this and stop the service, but I have not tried this.